# Get computer user's name

Tags: linux, windows, macos, node.js, gruntjs

I'm writing [a plugin](https://github.com/kentcdodds/grunt-clock) for [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and I need to be able to get the currently logged in user's username whether it be on a *nix or Windows operating system. I've looked around, but haven't found any good way to do this. Is this possible? I saw that it may work using [`process.env`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) but I read that this may not work on windows platforms quite like it does on *nix...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Linux and Windows store username in environment variable, but the the name of variable are different, this line of code is tested on both Centos 6, Windows 8:

```
var username = process.env.USER || process.env.USERNAME
```

Comment: But be aware that these, as they are just environment variables, can be changed at will before calling, so they are not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows: `%username%`

On Unix: `whoami`

Comment: As in... run those commands and take the output? I would love an answer in a `grunt` context if possible :)